# snapshot listener isFromCache() returning false

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am registering snapshot listener on my document reference. For first time, I am getting metadata isfromCache true and rest other time I am getting false. It should be opposite as no document is changing. I checked this value just to be sure that my datas after first time read are getting read from cache.

```
DocumentReference basicRef = usersRef.collection(DETAILS).document(BASIC_DETAILS);
ListenerRegistration basicListener = basicRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
                                @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    return;
                }

                if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
                    Log.d("debug", "Current data basic: " + snapshot.getMetadata().isFromCache());
                    BasicDetails basicDetails = snapshot.toObject(BasicDetails.class);
                    loadData(basicDetails);
                } else {
                    Log.d("debug", "Current data: null");
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `isFromCache` property is documented to be:

> `true` if the snapshot was created from cached data rather than **guaranteed up-to-date server data**.

So it being `false` does not necessarily mean the document was read from the server, as much as it means that the document is guaranteed to be up to date with the server.

To know what documents have changed, you can iterate over the documentChanged collection, as shown in the code above.

Also see:

- [Firebase always reads from internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59627868/firebase-always-reads-from-internet/59637177#59637177)

Comment: Okay got it. In vague terms, True means old cache and False means server or updated cache. Thank you so much for this. So what's happening in my case is probably for first time its getting data from cache thinking its old one. Then it checks with server confirms that its new one and then show false as it is updated cache.

Comment: Yeah, the name is definitely not intuitive. If you get `false` initially, it's most likely that the connection to the server hasn't resulted in data yet, and it gives you a local version of that data (so that you can show the UI as quickly as possible). If you don't want this local version, you can tell Firebase to not return those (check the docs for how). But I typically recommend against that, as showing the UI fast is far better. If needed you can show some indicated that the data may be outdated (e.g. by showing it flashing until you get a snapshot where `isFromCache` is false).

Comment: No its fine for me this way only. I want to load UI fast. I just wanted to ensure that I am not reading data from server each time. Thanks for your insights!